# How to pass json data to frontend using Django

Tags: json, django

I have response from another api of json data and i want to send this json data to my frontend to parse this json there

But when im using return JsonResponse it just returns html with json i dont need that, i want to return blank html with json which was send on front and frontend with js will parse it

views.py

```
def json_project_budget(request):

    session = requests_cache.CachedSession('project_budget_cache')

    url = config('REPORT_PROJECT_BUDGET')


    response = session.get(url=url, auth=UNICA_AUTH).json()

    queryset = []

    for item in response:
        my_js = json.dumps(item)

        parsed_json = ReportProjectBudgetSerializer.parse_raw(my_js)

        obj = parsed_json.ObjectGUID

        for budget in parsed_json.BudgetData:
            budget.SectionGUID = CleanSections.objects.get(GUID=budget.SectionGUID)
            budget.СompletedContract = budget.СompletedContract * 100
            budget.СompletedEstimate = budget.СompletedEstimate * 100
            queryset.append(budget)

    return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
```

I will update bcs i think that i understand my problem
I have problems in url or something like that

I have ListView which renders my template and the main question how am i suppose to send this function `json_project_budget` in my template to get json data?

views.pyy

```
class ShowProjectBudgetList(ListView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = ''
    template_name = 'customer/customer_home.html'
    context_object_name = 'json_list'
    allow_empty = True

    # paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        return None
```

urls.py

```
    path('customer/', ShowProjectBudgetList.as_view(), name='customer_view'),
    path('customer/', json_project_budget, name='json_project_budget'),
```

Comment: Im not rly sure mb i already send my json data to frontend how am i suppose to check that?

Comment: Its a bad idea to call apis inside a view. You can use a task scheduler like django-q or celery (more complex, but worth it). Then either wait for the response of the api inside the view (via the tass) and return its result or save the result in your own format to a database. Imagine a user spams your view 1000 times. This would result in 1000 api calls where you have 0 control. With a task-scheduler you can control everything or even save the data periodically if its not updating every second.